# How to move functions that work when run from a component to a service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I re-wrote this question to better get help on how to solve the problem.  Everything works great when I keep the code in my component.ts file and display it on the html page, but when I try to move it to a service, I get errors and no dynamic display.

component.ts

```
import { PagesService } from './../services/pages.service';
import { Page } from './../admin/pages/page.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SERVER_URL } from '../../../src/environments/environment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-partner',
  templateUrl: './partner.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner.page.scss'],
})
export class PartnerPage implements OnInit {
  public pageList: Array<Page> = Array<Page>();
  fileName: string = "partner";
  page: Page;
  constructor(private pgsService: PagesService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  GetPages() {
    this.http.get(`${SERVER_URL}api/pages`)
    .subscribe(res=>this.Success(res),res=>this.Error(res));
  }
  GetPage(fileName: string) {
      this.http.get(`${SERVER_URL}api/pageName/${fileName}`)
    .subscribe(res=>this.SuccessPage(res), res=>this.Error(res));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetPages();
    this.GetPage(this.fileName);

  }
  Error(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
 Success(res) {
   console.log(res);
   this.pageList = res;
   console.log("this.pageList",this.pageList);
 }
 SuccessPage(res) {
   this.page = res;
   console.log("this.page",this.page);
 }

}
```

partner.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-title>{{page?.title}}</ion-title>
  <div class="partner-wrap">
    <ion-text>
      <h1 class="partner-header">{{page?.heading}}</h1>
      <img src="../../assets/partnerupogo.png" alt="PartnerUp!">
        <div [innerHtml]='page?.content'></div>
    </ion-text>
  </div>
  <div>{{page?.footer}}</div>
</ion-content>
```

My proposed pages.service.ts

```
import { PagesService } from './../services/pages.service';
import { Page } from './../admin/pages/page.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SERVER_URL } from '../../../src/environments/environment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-partner',
  templateUrl: './partner.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner.page.scss'],
})
export class PartnerPage implements OnInit {

  public page: Page;
  fileName: string = "partner";
  constructor(public pgsService: PagesService, public http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pgsService.GetPage(this.fileName)
    .subscribe(res=>this.pgsService.SuccessPage(res),res=>this.pgsService.Error(res));
    this.page = this.pgsService.page;

  }

}
```

I tried copying the functions to a service, and running things through the service but it didn't work.  The functions would run and console.log through the service but I couldn't pass the data to the component to display in the html.

I get *ERROR in src/app/partner/partner.page.ts(21,6): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.*

How do I convert this so it works?

Comment: If possible then provide stackblitz

Comment: You have to learn about the `asynchronous` things on earth and maybe return something from the service method to the component.

Comment: I tried uploading files to stackblitz but have never used it before.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dd5ch

Comment: @SachinGupta I agree, that's part of why I'm asking for help.  I've been trying to learn it and can't seem to get this right.

Comment: OK.  I got the page to display by returning my GetPage() method, but I'm getting a ton of type errors:
PartnerPage.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Service' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Answer (score 0):

// the code is asynchrones
//GET ALL THE PAGES -> services you turned into a promise

```
getPages() {
    return this.http
      .get<Page[]>(`${SERVER_URL}api/pages`)
      .pipe(
       map(pages => {
      //for each record in the results
          for (let page of pages) {
        //return an empty array if no links
            if (!page["links"]) {
              page["links"] = [];
          }
        }
        return pages;
      })
    )
  .toPromise();
}
```

// in your component listPages;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPages();
  }
async getPages() {
    try {
      this.listPages = await this.pagesService.getPages();
      console.log(this.listPages);
   } catch (error) {}
```

}

Comment: I tried this, but still get undefined when I try to console.log anything from my component.  The correct results are being logged from the service, though.

Answer (score 0):

OH!  I FINALLY DID IT!

First, I needed to add return before the http request, so it could be sent to the component.

```
GetPage(fileName: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${SERVER_URL}api/pageName/${fileName}`);
  }
```

Then I needed to use the ? when using string interpolation so I didn't get a ton of errors displaying the page.  I also had a typo in the html.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-title>{{pgsService?.page?.title}}</ion-title>
  <div class="partner-wrap">
    <ion-text>
      <h1 class="partner-header">{{pgsService?.page?.heading}}</h1>
      <img src="../../assets/partnerupogo.png" alt="PartnerUp!">
        <div [innerHtml]='pgsService.page?.content'></div>
    </ion-text>
  </div>
  <div>{{pgsService?.page?.footer}}</div>
</ion-content>
```

Now it finally works as a service, and without errors!  I'm open to answers that may be considered the right way to do this, in case this isn't the best way.